# Changing Only Certain Bits in Byte in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a PCF8574 and I have a set of configurations that I need to send to the device. I have communication working and I'm using an I2C write_byte command. In the table below if a cell doesn't have a value then it's state should not be changed.

[image]

I know it's a bit manipulation "game" to get the combination of operators correct but I'm not having luck so far finding the right combination to yield what I want.

As an example, when the PCF8574 is powered up it's default state is `0b11111111`. If I want to change to state 'B' (0bxxx10x1x, where x means don't change) what function could I create which would set the part to correctly be `0b11110111`?

My current test solution isn't the way I think it should be implemented but it seems to work:

```
from smbus2 import SMBus
i2c_port_num = 1
pcfAddress = 0x38
pcfBits = 'xxx00xxx'

curSetting = i2cBus.read_byte(pcfAddress)

def checkBit(newSetting, bits):
    for i in range(0, len(bits)):
        if(bits[i]) != 'x':
            print("position", i, "is", bits[i])
            if int(bits[i]) == 0:
                newSetting &=~(1<<i)
            elif int(bits[i]) == 1:
                newSetting |= (1<<i)
    return(newSetting)

changeState = checkBit(curSetting, pcfBits)
i2cBus.write_byte(pcfAddress, changeState)
```

Comment: That's the standard code for setting and clearing bits.

Comment: Except I think you're counting bits from the wrong end.

Comment: It should be `(1 << (7-i))`

Comment: I was thinking there should be a "better" way than using a text representation and cycling through each position. I should be able to create some sort of mask and state and then use AND/OR combination to get the correct byte to write.

Comment: The problem is that you need 3 states: set, clear, and leave alone. The string with `x` in it seems like a good way to do that.

Comment: Another option would be to pass two bitmasks: one with all the bits to set, another with all the bits to clear.

Comment: I haven't fully tested this implementation so your correction could be correct. It just "feels wrong" to have to resort to using strings to manipulate binary data

Comment: The two bitmasks method would be cleaner, it doesn't need any loops: `result = oldValue | bitsToSet & ~bitsToClear`

Comment: Yes, two bitmasks was the line of thinking I was trying to come up with but failed at creating, hence my posted question.

Comment: Is this the masks you were thinking of when looking at STATE B

`oldvalue = 0b11111111`
`bitsToSet = 0b00010010`
`bitsToClear = 0b00001000`

Comment: It needs parentheses. `bin((bits | bitsToSet) & ~bitsToClear) == '0b11110111'`

Comment: Yes, I agree, thanks, I believe this would work!